# LWC Routing using Navigo ; Getting Error ->e.replace is not a function

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

```
<template for:each={menuItems} for:item="menuItem">
                <li key={menuItem.location} class="menu-item" href={menuItem.location} onclick={handleMenuItemClick}>
                    {menuItem.title}
                </li>
            </template>
```

```
 menuItems = [
        { title: 'Home', location: '/home' },
        { title: 'UI', location: '/ui' },
    ];
    constructor() {
        super(); 
        this.router.on({
            '/home': async () => {
                const { default: ViewHome } = await import('view/home');
                this.setPage('view-home', ViewHome);
            },
            '/ui': async () => {
                const { default: ViewUi } = await import('view/ui');
                this.setPage('view-ui', ViewUi);
            },

        });

    handleMenuItemClick(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const href  = evt.target;

        console.log('aa',href);
        this.router.navigate(href, true);

    }
Value of href = <li href="/home" class="menu-item">Home</li>
```

When i click on li element,i want to route to that LWC component page.

Comment: Please include more code context and a detailed description of your issue via an [edit].

Comment: Added more details.
For more reference.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266551/lwc-best-practice-for-routing